# Can't run rspec in WSL from RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rubymine

I'm trying to trigger running RSpec from RubyMine when using WSL to run Ruby. I can successfully start the server but when running RSpec I get this error:

```
C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu --exec /bin/sh -c "export HOME=/home/pupeno && export RUBYMINE_TESTUNIT_REPORTER='/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/RubyMine 2021.2.1/plugins/ruby/rb/testing/patch/testunit' && export WSL_DISTRO_NAME=Ubuntu && export TEAMCIY_RAKE_TU_AUTORUNNER_PATH=/home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/test-unit-3.3.7/lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb && export SHELL=/bin/sh && export LOGNAME=pupeno && export WSLENV='' && export HOSTTYPE=x86_64 && export ANSICON='' && export TERM=xterm-256color && export NAME=assc && export DISABLE_SPRING=true && export RUBYLIB='/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/RubyMine 2021.2.1/plugins/ruby/rb/testing/patch/common:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/RubyMine 2021.2.1/plugins/ruby/rb/testing/patch/rake:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/RubyMine 2021.2.1/plugins/ruby/rb/testing/patch/testunit' && export TEAMCITY_RAKE_RUNNER_USED_FRAMEWORKS=':test_unit :shoulda ' && export USER=pupeno && export SPEC_OPTS='--require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter' && export PWD='/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/RubyMine 2021.2.1/jbr/bin' && export PATH='$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program' && export LANG=C.UTF-8 && export RM_INFO=RM-212.5080.58 && export TEAMCITY_RAKE_RUNNER_MODE=idea && export TEAMCITY_RAKE_TU_TESTRUNNERMADIATOR_PATH=/home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/test-unit-3.3.7/lib/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb && cd /mnt/c/Users/pupeno/Code/PandemicAssistant && bash -c 'env RBENV_VERSION=3.0.2 /home/pupeno/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec ruby /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/bin/rails spec'"
Testing started at 10:22 ...
/home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/bin/ruby -I/home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib:/home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-support-3.10.2/lib /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb
/home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:235:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec/runner/formatter/teamcity_formatter (LoadError)
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:235:in `rescue in custom_formatter'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:232:in `custom_formatter'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:183:in `find_formatter'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:152:in `add'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:974:in `add_formatter'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:118:in `block in load_formatters_into'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:118:in `each'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:118:in `load_formatters_into'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:24:in `configure'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:132:in `configure'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:99:in `setup'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<main>'
/home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:233:in `block in custom_formatter': uninitialized constant Spec (NameError)
Did you mean?  RSpec
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:233:in `each'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:233:in `inject'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:233:in `custom_formatter'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:183:in `find_formatter'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:152:in `add'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:974:in `add_formatter'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:118:in `block in load_formatters_into'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:118:in `each'

An error occurred while loading teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter.
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:118:in `load_formatters_into'
Failure/Error: __send__(method, file)
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:24:in `configure'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:132:in `configure'

LoadError:
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:99:in `setup'
  cannot load such file -- teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2112:in `require'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2112:in `load_file_handling_errors'
    from /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<main>'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1574:in `block in requires='
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1574:in `each'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1574:in `requires='
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:113:in `block in process_options_into'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:112:in `each'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:112:in `process_options_into'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:22:in `configure'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:132:in `configure'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:99:in `setup'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
# /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<main>'
/home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/bin/ruby -I/home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib:/home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-support-3.10.2/lib /home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb failed
# 
#   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
#   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
#   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
No examples found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any ideas what's going on?

I tried installing `teamcity_formatter` and running rspec in `bundle exec` but the error was the same.

I can successfully run them from a WSL console by running any of:

- `rspec`
- `bundle exec rspec`
- `rake spec`

I'm running RubyMine 2021.2.1, Ruby 3.0.2, Rails 6.1.4.1, RSpec 3.10.1, rspec-rails 5.0.2.

Comment: Could you specify whether the project resides inside WSL host or in Windows FS?

Comment: @Olivia: the project is in Windows FS.

Comment: Could you please specify your RubyMine version? Does the same happen in 2021.2.1? Does it happen with projects where Ruby version is lower than 3.0.2?

Comment: @Olivia I'm running RubyMine 2021.2.1, Ruby 3.0.2, Rails 6.1.4.1, RSpec 3.10.1, rspec-rails 5.0.2. I don't know about an older Ruby, I actually don't have one installed.

Comment: Which WSL version are you running? Is it WSL2? Please specify also your Windows OS version (in case it's Win11 there're certain issues related to WSL)

Comment: Yes, WSL2 on Windows 10.

Comment: Checked with WSL2 + Win10 + rvm:ruby 3.0.2 + rspec 3.10.1 and it worked fine so could you please submit an issue on RubyMine's tracker with a sample project for reproduce: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix: install `rspec`. Install plain `rspec` on top of `rspec-rails` and it starts working. I'm not sure why.